# MYSQL two table sort TRICKY

Tags: mysql

Good morning please I have question if someone will know... This is tricky question... I have two column

```
date        active
20180211    0
20180100    0
20171208    1
```

I need sort it by `active 1 + date` first and then all sort by `active 0 + date`....

Expected result:

```
date        active
20171208    1
20180211    0
20180100    0
```

Working solution without problem

```
SELECT * FROM xy ORDER BY active DESC, date DESC
```

Now I need implement clause **WHERE** because there will be xy results and here is problem.

```
SELECT * FROM xy WHERE date < 20171208 ORDER BY active DESC, date DESC LIMIT 1
```

This doesnt work, this is still processed without ORDER and "20171208" is last result in mysql (order is not applied)... Maybee need group or something

Thank you very much for any answer. Best regards P.

Comment: What is the type of your `date` column?

Comment: you have not date < 20171208 ... sure the query return rows ???

Comment: Yes, this not returning rows because it is not SORTED and 20171208  is last result... there is not lesser then 20171208 and this is problem ORDER is not applied with clasuse WHERE.... I need 20171208  be on top of results because has "active = 1" and mysql is not applied this ORDER clause.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I am using VARCHAR(255) i do not use DATE(), i dont want DATE() ..

Comment: The where and limit clause in your query make no sense in relation to the rest of your question and why do you suspect you need a group by?

Comment: Because WHERE is processed first in mysql and ORDER second ... And I need first order and then WHERE... Simple write first ORDER in command is not possible, I have to start with WHERE. I am not expert in MYSQL I am very sorry.

Comment: I'm not getting it, are you saying you want only 1 (the most recent) row returned with active = 1 and all the rows with active = 0?

Comment: ok simple... i need all rows... but i need first see active=1 and then active=0.... and second is order it by date.... BUT here is one tricky stuff... i need use clause WHERE because i need cut results from mysql and use HTML page 1, 2, 3, 4 and etc... when last result end in 20171208 then i will continune WHERE date < 20171208 and etc.. but this doesnt work correctly... Is not ordering properly and i cant use WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

It obvious that you don't have date prior to 20171208 so the result is an empty set.

The order by clause will apply to the results only, meaning that the query will execute first the where clause and then order the filtered results. You can not expect to do the order by first and then the where part of the query.

Please find the sqlFiddle I created and see that it is working fine when you put <= instead of < in the query condition

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7609ba/18

Comment: This still doesnt work.... Clause ORDER is not applied and 20171208  is last result.. But thank you very much for your effort and sqlfiddle.com example. Please if you know some idea I will be very happy how to sort it this issue.

Comment: The results of the query are as expected. I see nothing strange about the results. What do you expect as a result or which query? Could you explain a little better because the sentence  'ORDER is not applied and 20171208 is last result' is not so clear.

Comment: I am very sorry for misunderstanding..... ok easy... I need first "20171208 with active 1" because there is active=1 and next will be "20180211 with active 0" and "20180100  with active 0" ... I am trying use order active DESC, date DESC but clause WHERE is processed first in MYSQL and this is problem. I do not know how to reverse WHERE with ORDER... I think is not possible in normal way.

Comment: There is no way of reversing the execution order of WHERE and ORDER BY. IF you really need to execute the WHERE first and then the ORDER BY you can write a subquery. Please see the query I added to sqlFiddle.

Comment: Please can you send this sqlfiddle? I can not see it. I am very thank you for your help, I am not expert in mysql and this is little bit critical.

Comment: Thank you great job, I am trying it... It looks like it will works but it not working i dont know why...
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c37e7/29
if you remove WHERE outside ( )..... Result will be correctly sorted... But if you add this WHERE outside ( ) it is again not working properly... i dont know why... is maybee bug.. because in normal way they should show us all rows without first one "20171208" because we sorted it already inside ( ) ... but they again show as "20171208" as a last row in the table and they dont use ORDERED results inside ( )...